# FastAPI - Struggling to use dependency injection to inject a service class into an endpoint

Tags: python, fastapi

I have an AI related FastAPI application, and I have the business logic nicely separated into multiple services. I want to use inject these services into my application so I can use them, but I can't get it to work. These are the services I have:

aws_rekognition_service.py

```
from io import BytesIO

# AWS SDK
import boto3


class AWSRekognitionService:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = boto3.client("rekognition")

    # rest of the business logic
```

grounding_dino_service.py

```
import torch
from PIL import Image

# Grounding DINO.
import groundingdino.datasets.transforms as T
from groundingdino.models import build_model
from groundingdino.util.slconfig import SLConfig
from groundingdino.util.utils import (
    clean_state_dict,
    get_phrases_from_posmap,
)


class GroundingDINOService:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    # rest of the business logic
```

image_segmentation_service.py

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image

# Services
from aws_rekognition_service import AWSRekognitionService

# Initialize service
aws_rekognition_service = AWSRekognitionService()


class ImageSegmentationService:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    # rest of the business logic
```

segment_anything_service.py

```
import cv2
import torch

# Segment Anything.
from segment_anything import build_sam, SamPredictor

# Services.
from grounding_dino_service import GroundingDINOService

# Initialize services.
grounding_dino_service = GroundingDINOService()


class SegmentAnythingService:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    # rest of the business logic
```

visualization_service.py

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import json
import torch
import cv2


class VisualizationService:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    # rest of the business logic
```

Two services depend on AWSRekognitionService. Besides that, I have one main service, book_recognition_service.py, which uses all services above:

```
import os
import json

# Services.
from grounding_dino_service import GroundingDINOService
from image_segmentation_service import ImageSegmentationService
from segment_anything_service import SegmentAnythingService
from visualization_service import VisualizationService

# Initialize services.
grounding_dino_service = GroundingDINOService()
image_segmentation_service = ImageSegmentationService()
segment_anything_service = SegmentAnythingService()
visualization_service = VisualizationService()

with open("../config/ml_config.json") as json_file:
    config = json.load(json_file)


class BookRecognitionService:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    async def recognize():
        # business logic
```

I want to inject the BookRecognitionService into one of my routers so I can use it in an endpoint, and I thought it would be as simple as doing this in my book router:

book.py

```
...

# Services.
from services.book_recognition_service import BookRecognitionService

# Instantiate services.
book_recognition_service = BookRecognitionService()

@router.get("/recognize", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def recognize_boks():
    book_texts = await book_recognition_service.recognize()
    return JSONResponse(status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK, content=book_texts)

...
```

Sadly, this does not work. This is my main.py file:

```
# FastAPI
from fastapi import FastAPI

# MongoDB driver
from motor.motor_asyncio import AsyncIOMotorClient
from config import mongo_config

# Router imports
from routers import auth, book


app = FastAPI()


@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_mongo_client():
    app.mongodb_client = AsyncIOMotorClient(mongo_config.MONGO_URI)
    app.mongodb = app.mongodb_client[mongo_config.MONGO_DB_NAME]


@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def shutdown_mongo_client():
    app.mongodb_client.close()


app.include_router(auth.router)
app.include_router(book.router)
```

When running my FastAPI application, I now get the following error stack:

```
  File "C:\Users\Stefan\book-recognizer-backend\api\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from routers import auth, book
  File "C:\Users\Stefan\book-recognizer-backend\api\routers\book.py", line 15, in <module>
    from services.book_recognition_service import BookRecognitionService
  File "C:\Users\Stefan\book-recognizer-backend\api\services\book_recognition_service.py", line 5, in <module>
    from grounding_dino_service import GroundingDINOService
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'grounding_dino_service'
```

And this goes for all services. My question is: how do I properly inject the BookRecognitionService into my book router so I can use its functionality in an API endpoint? I'm very new to FastAPI and the dependency injection documentation is not really helping. Thank you in advance!

Comment: This isn't a FastAPI error; it's just a standard python import error.  Your book_recognition_service can't see the module it needs to import.  They should be in the same directory, or, ideally, inside a package with relative (dot) imports.

Comment: from a quick glance you don't seem to be using dependency injection at all, but it's late and there' s a lot of text in this Q so I probably missed it.

Comment: There is no dependency injection taking place here (which would be implemented through `Depends()` or `Security()` in FastAPI normally); the problem is as 2e0byo says with regular Python imports; answering that is hard without having any knowledge about how you're running your application (i.e. poetry?), how you're installing your modules (`pip install -e .`), what `setup.py` looks like, whether you're changing the python path yourself, how you're running your application, etc.